# Where to put the style guide in an R package

Tags: r, r-package, readme

I am currently working on a GitHub-based R package and I would like to add markdown text containing coding style guidelines. The problem is that I can't find the best place to put that information. According to [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-structure), I can't just add a STYLE.md file without having the package fail basic build checks. They say:

> The sources of an R package consists of a subdirectory containing a
>   files DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE, and the subdirectories R, data, demo,
>   exec, inst, man, po, src, tests, tools and vignettes (some of which
>   can be missing, but which should not be empty). The package
>   subdirectory may also contain files INDEX, configure, cleanup,
>   LICENSE, LICENCE and NEWS. Other files such as INSTALL (for
>   non-standard installation instructions), README/README.md, or
>   ChangeLog will be ignored by R, but may be useful to end users.

So my current solution is to integrate the style guide into README.md file, but I don't like to have it there, because the guide is a secondary thing written for the package contributors and not the users; it should not be visible for everybody visiting the package's homepage (which is what happens for anything written in README.md and pushed to GitHub).

Another thing I thought about doing was to create a vignette for that; the developers of the rockchalk package [did just that](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rockchalk/). However, my guide is much shorter, I don't think it fits well with the spotlight and printing-friendly format of vignettes.

Where else could/should I put the style guide?

Comment: Put it in the inst directory if you literally want to include it in your distribution.  However you are more likely going to want to include it in your .rbuildignore file.  same thing goes for CONTRIBUTING.md and similar items that you want people to find on your github repo.

Comment: I would second @Elin's advice to add `STYLE.md` (and/or `CONTRIBUTING.md`) to your `.Rbuildignore` file. I write separately to let you know where in Writing R Extensions to find this topic: [Section 1.3.2](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Building-package-tarballs). It's rather brief about it, but that's where they mention you can exclude files from the build with `.Rbuildignore`.

Comment: To clarify, Elin's advice to put the style guide in your .rbuildignore file means to put the filename of the style guide in your .rbuildignore file.

Comment: @Elin and duckmayr, thank you for the input, it seems like a good way to address the question.